# how to extract a specific string and make it as a new variable in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large size of excel sheet with 117 columns and 8000 rows.
What I want to do is simply to extract date which is a part of this large excel sheet.
Basically the file looks like this:

```
A     B                 C           D             E
NaN   NaN              NaN         NaN           NaN
Nan   update date:   2020-08-30    NaN           NaN
NaN   NaN             NaN         Client:       Steve
```

What I have tried was looking for the specific character to help me extract the date. Here is the script:

```
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    for col in range(df.shape[1]):
        if str(df.iat[row,col]) == 'update date:':
            row_datestart = row
        if str(df.iat[row,col]) == 'Client:':
            col_dateend = col-1

periode = df[col_dateend].values[row_datestart]
```

First, I tried to check whether I got the correct row and column or not, and It showed that it's correct. But somehow when I extracted the date to be a new variable, it gave me an error.

I often used this script, but I don't know why it doesn't work work this data.

is there any other way I can do to extract the date and make it as a new variable?

Thankyou.

Comment: Please share the error you got while assigning the value to the variable.

Comment: it didn't show the specific problems, it gave me '3', which is the column number I want